# Huawei P8 with or without dual sim?

Tags: huawei, dual-sim

I found out that Huawei P8 (not lite, not plus) supports dual sim, when I can insert only 1 sim and 1 sd, without possibility to swich sd for second sim. I tried micro and nano sim and none fits to sd slot.
Are there two versions of Huawei P8? Is it possible to check whether my phone supports dual sim?

Comment: There is indeed a single SIM variant of P8 (GRA-L09), and additionally it is mainly sold internationally (e.g. Europe) - do you have this variant?

Comment: Unfortunately... DualSim variant has code GRA-UL00. Post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several variants for P8:

[GRA-UL00](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=7982&c=huawei_p8_standard_edition_gra-ul00_dual_sim_td-lte) - LTE/WCDMA for China Unicom ("open"), dual SIM;

[GRA-TL00](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=8019&c=huawei_p8_standard_edition_gra-tl00_dual_sim_td-lte) - TD-LTE/TD-SCDMA for China Mobile, dual SIM;

[GRA-CL00](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=8013&c=huawei_p8_standard_edition_gra-cl00_dual_sim_td-lte) - LTE/CDMA for China Telecom, dual SIM;

(the 3 above comes with GRA-*L10 sub-variants with 64GB storage instead of 16GB)

...and finally [GRA-L09](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=7977&c=huawei_p8_standard_edition_gra-l09_td-lte) - international LTE with European bands, single SIM.

The dual SIM variants have one slot for either a nano-SIM or a MicroSD card, and a dedicated slot for a nano-SIM, as shown below. You did mention that one SD and one nano-SIM can be inserted at the same time - that means you do own a dual SIM variant, just didn't get the correct way to utilize it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Huawei P8 has dual SIM support. You should put the 2nd nano SIM "vertically" so that it fits into the slot.

[image: A]

Comment: Hmmm... Stack Exchange does not allow image links in HTTP. Sad.

Comment: Posted an answer myself then saw you already used literally the same pic in link form... *facepalm*